# Where is the documentation for the full_output option of scipy curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510227/python-scipy-implementing-optimize-curve-fit-s-sigma-into-optimize-leastsq/16528775#16528775) mentions using the full_output option of scipy to get extra data, including more info about quality of fit:

```
pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, sigma = SD, full_output = True)
```

I don't see any mention of the full_output option in the [scipy curve_fit documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) after some searching (google, scipy docs).

Can anyone provide a link to some documentation?

If not, can someone describe the extra return data and how it can be used?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq it is an argument to `leastsq`  and `curve_fit` is built on top of that (see kwargs part).

Comment: @ayhan is right. The linked documentation states: "kwargs: Keyword arguments passed to leastsq ". Just click on the link there and read accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ayhan's comment:  docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/… it is an argument to leastsq and curve_fit is built on top of that (see kwargs part)